# How to Log exceptions in Mongodb Version 4 With Winston Version 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, winston, error-logging

I found that I can use the Winston-mongodb package but it supports only the earlier version of mongodb and winston. Is there a way to Log exception in mongodb for the last version which is 4 using the last version of winston?